# YouTube API (PHP) - Retrieving a private video under my account

Tags: video, private, youtube-api

I'm using Zend_Gdata_YouTube to interface with the YouTube API to upload videos from my site. The videos are uploaded as "private":

```
$myVideoEntry->setVideoPrivate();
```

...and have unique tags and developer tags. An admin can then go into a custom CMS and approve the private user-submitted entries and make them public - at least, that's what I want to do.

In the CMS, I connect to the API as an authenticated user (Zend_Gdata_AuthSub). I can pull the authenticated user's video like so:

```
$videoFeed = $yt->getuserUploads('default');
```

This will pull all the videos, both private and public. But when I try to search for a specific video with a search term:

```
$query = $yt->newVideoQuery();
$query->setSafeSearch('none');
$query->setVideoQuery('puppies');

$videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($query->getQueryUrl(2));
```

Or by tag:

```
$query = $yt->newVideoQuery();
$query->setOrderBy('viewCount');
$query->setRacy('include');
$query->setCategory('People/sometag');

// obtain a feed with videos matching the provided tag
$videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($query);
```

Or by developer tag:

```
$devTagUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com' .
    '%2Fschemas%2F2007%2Fdevelopertags.cat%7D' . $some_dev_tag;
$videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($devTagUrl);
```

The private videos will return an empty result. However, if I make the video public, then I can pull it from any of the three methods above - all of which are being executed under an authenticated connection.

How can I pull a private video based on tag or developer tag? Am I missing something? Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this seems to be a limitation of the API. My work around solution was to pull all the user's videos with:

```
$videoFeed = $yt->getuserUploads('default');
```

Which pulls the public and private videos. Then I compare my dev tags with each entry and match up the videos in PHP.