# Using the YouTube API v3 to list all private videos

Tags: php, video, youtube-api, private

Currently I'm building a site that will use a small number of user uploaded videos. These videos are uploaded to the server, then moved on to YouTube via the API v3. The private tag is set, and all videos are uploaded into one central account.

My problem is; how can I access and list all these private videos via the API to display on my site? I'm not sure if this is possible. Any feed back would be much appreciated.

After looking into it more I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677453/youtube-api-php-retrieving-a-private-video-under-my-account?rq=1). After looking through the docs I couldn't find a PHP specific example of how I could do this: getuserUploads.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you can do that, using the YouTube Data v3, in this way:

Get the uploaded videos in this way (it is a Java example):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#examples

And then you can retrieve the videos resources for these playlistitems using:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

And then you can verify the status.privacyStatus in each video resource (if you upload videos with a different status.privacyStatus .. )

Comment: Ah! That's it. I'm having some trouble with it though. For [the listChannels](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) I cannot find the unique id. [Here](http://codepad.org/yq9aD00v) is my current try.

Comment: You can use the parameter "mine" to retrieve the channels owned by the authenticated user.

Comment: I know, however having to auth each time would defeat the point of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

1. Get the ZF Gdata Library @ http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest
2. Run the Autoloader:

   ```
   set_include_path(APPPATH . 'third_party/zf/' . get_include_path());
   require 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
   Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
   ```
3. Create an HTTP Instance with your youtube Login, Password, and Developer Key (Youll have to grab one).

   ```
      $httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
               "Youtube LOGIN", 
               "Youtube PASSWORD", 
               'youtube'
       );
   ```
4. Instantiate GData with your cedentials

   ```
       $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube(
               $httpClient, 
               null,
               null, 
               "Youtube Developer Key"
       );
   ```
5. Fetch your playlist

   ```
       $playlistListFeed = $yt->getPlaylistListFeed("YOUR YOUTUBE CHANNEL NAME");
       //print_r($playlistListFeed); // uncomment to see the goods
   ```
6. Prepare an array to sort through less data

   ```
       $data['feed'] = array();
   ```
7. Loop through everything, use the **is_private** to tell if its private or not

   ```
       foreach ($playlistListFeed as $playlistEntry) 
       {
         $feedUrl = $playlistEntry->getPlaylistVideoFeedUrl();
         $playlistVideoFeed = $yt->getPlaylistVideoFeed($feedUrl);

         foreach ($playlistVideoFeed as $video) {

           $data['feed'][] = array(
               'id' => $video->getVideoId(),
               'title' => $video->getTitle(),
               'thumbnail' => $video->getVideoThumbnails(),
               'is_private' => $video->isVideoPrivate(),
               'url' => $video->getVideoWatchPageUrl(),
               'flash_url' => $video->getFlashPlayerUrl ()
           );
       }

   }
   ```

You may have to tinker around with it to get it right to your settings, hope this helps.

Comment: Hey JREAM. Thanks for your contribution. I did specify I wanted to use the youtube api v3. I love your videos btw; you may not remember me. I'm the pirate that contacted you ages ago.

Comment: Haha thanks.. Im terribly sorry I had just been working with YouTube a minute ago so I thought I'd share.. Not to be ignorant, but is V3 API available in GData?

Comment: I don't believe so. http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ That's the library I'm using.